# c# Uri Templates

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I'm new to REST service development and I am currently writing a WCF Rest Service which must support an existing calling format.

I know that by adding

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "{id}/testid.xml")]
string testid(string id);
```

to my webmethod the request will be made using:

http://[hostname]/255/testid.xml

What I want is to be able do make the request using
http://255/[hostname]/testid.xml

Please note that the service is hosted in a Windows Service Application.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The structure of a given URI is as follows:

eg http://host/path?q=x

This can be broken down into:

- http:// - the *Scheme*
- host/ - the *Authority*
- path - the *Path*
- ?q=x - the *Querystring*

URI templating works on the Path and Querystring components of the URI only. The Scheme and the Authority cannot be accessed in this way.

Answer (score 0):

To use special characters inside parameters on the URL you must configure the HttpListenerRequestUriBuilder. This builder unescape or not the encoding based on a setting. You can add this code to your app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpListener unescapeRequestUrl="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The OP's question is about how to have the URI template parameter before the hostname in the URI path. Not how to escape special character

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. you can't add parameter or can't pass parameter in uri before domain name and service name. You can add parameter after domain and service name in Uri.